# Calcular tamanho de vetor

Tags: c, array

Como calcular o tamanho do vetor?

Meu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int retornaMediana(int *vetor){

int tam=0;

    tam = sizeof(vetor);

    printf("TESTE: %d, %d, %d\n\n",vetor[0],vetor[1],vetor[2]);

    return tam;

}

void main(){

int vetor[] = {5,25,7,10,13,33,45,11,60};
int n = retornaMediana(&vetor);
int n2;

n2 = sizeof(vetor)/sizeof(int);

    printf("TAMANHO = %d\n\n",n);
    printf("TAMANHO = %d\n\n",n2);


}
```

Como que eu faço pra função retornar o real tamanho do vetor ? Já passei por parâmetro, referência e nada, só recebo esse 4 como resposta.

Comment: E qual o resultado que você espera? Porque?

Comment: Qual é a finalidade do `n2 = sizeof(vetor) / sizeof(int);`?

Comment: Por favor, não altere o código na pergunta depois que ela foi feita - uma das respostas aponta para partes do código que mudaram e isso torna muito difícil acompanhar qualquer coisa.

Comment: Essa função era pra retornar tam, sendo o tamanho do vetor, ou seja, uma função que recebesse um vetor, e retornasse o seu tamanho.

Comment: o n2 era apenas um teste na main para testar se o sizeof funcionava.

Comment: Você quer o tamanho do vetor em bytes? é isso?

Comment: Aconselho uma leitura do [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/), especialmente a secção 6.

Answer (score 3):

Esta linha está calculando o tamanho corretamente:

```
int len = sizeof(vetor)/sizeof(int);
```

Melhor seria

```
int len = sizeof(vetor)/sizeof(vetor[0]);
```

pois, caso você mude o tipo do `vetor`, não será surpreendido por um *bug* difícil de se perceber dependendo do contexto.

Importante entender que o `sizeof` já é resolvido pelo compilador, pois ele simplesmente já sabe o que foi feito na definição da variável, portanto, se precisar saber o tamanho de um vetor passado por parâmetro, a solução que resta é sempre passar o vetor e o tamanho.

Voltando ao seu código, o problema é que você está calculando certo o tamanho, porém acaba sobreescrevendo o valor nesta outra linha, desta vez com o tamanho do ponteiro:

```
tam = sizeof(vetor);
```

Uma saída seria calcular o tamanho dentro do escopo da declaração, como você já estava fazendo, e enviar o tamanho para a função da mediana.

Veja a diferença:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int retornaMediana(int *vetor, int tam){
    // -- aqui você corre os ítens e calcula a mediana --
    // return mediana;
    printf("TESTE: %d, %d, %d\n\n",vetor[0],vetor[1],vetor[2]);
    return tam;
}

void main(){
    int vetor[] = {5,25,7,10,13,33,45,11,60};
    int len = sizeof(vetor)/sizeof(vetor[0]);

    int n  = retornaMediana( vetor, len );

    printf("TAMANHO = %d\n\n",n);
    printf("TAMANHO = %d\n\n",len);
}
```

Aqui tem uma demonstração no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/BvVgxy)**.

Comment: mas vamos supor que eu queira uma função que receba apenas um vetor, e retorne o seu tamanho..

Comment: Sempre você vai precisar passar o tamanho. O `sizeof` funciona no momento da compilação.

Answer (score 1):

Localmente se pode simplesmente chamar sizeof para calcular o tamanho do array, porém é sabido que em C, somente é passado o ponteiro do vetor para determinada função, então necessário percorrer o ponteiro para calcular o tamanho do vetor

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define lenvetor(vetor)    (sizeof(vetor)/sizeof(vetor[0]))
#define VECSIZE            19

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

int lenarraychar(char *a[]) {
   int nlen = 0;

   while(*(a++)) {
      //while(*(a+nlen)){
      //while(a[nlen]){
      nlen++;
   }
   return nlen;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

int lenarrayint(int p[]) {
   int nlen = 0;
   
   while(*(p++) || *p == 0 ) {
      nlen++;
   }
   return(nlen);
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

int main() {
   char *menustatic[VECSIZE] = {"Incluir", "Remover", "Listar", "Imprimir", 0};
   char *menudinamic[]       = {"Incluir", "Remover", "Listar", "Imprimir", 0};
   int vetorstatic[VECSIZE]  = {5,25,7,10,13,33,45,11,60,-1};
   int vetordinamic[]        = {5,25,7,10,13,33,45,11,60,-1};

   for(int i=0; i<VECSIZE; i++)
      printf("vetor[%d] = %02d\n", i, vetorstatic[i]);

   printf("============================\n");
   printf("TAMANHO menustatic   = %d\n",  lenarraychar(menustatic));
   printf("TAMANHO menustatic   = %d\n",  lenvetor(menustatic));
   printf("============================\n");
   printf("TAMANHO vetorstatic  = %d\n",  sizeof(vetorstatic)/sizeof(vetorstatic[0]));
   printf("TAMANHO vetorstatic  = %d\n",  lenvetor(vetorstatic));
   printf("TAMANHO vetorstatic  = %d\n",  lenarrayint(vetorstatic));
   printf("============================\n");
   printf("TAMANHO vetordinamic = %d\n",  sizeof(vetordinamic)/sizeof(vetordinamic[0]));
   printf("TAMANHO vetordinamic = %d\n",  lenvetor(vetordinamic));
   printf("TAMANHO vetordinamic = %d\n",  lenarrayint(vetordinamic));

   return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
vetor[0] = 05
vetor[1] = 25
vetor[2] = 07
vetor[3] = 10
vetor[4] = 13
vetor[5] = 33
vetor[6] = 45
vetor[7] = 11
vetor[8] = 60
vetor[9] = -1
vetor[10] = 00
vetor[11] = 00
vetor[12] = 00
vetor[13] = 00
vetor[14] = 00
vetor[15] = 00
vetor[16] = 00
vetor[17] = 00
vetor[18] = 00
============================
TAMANHO menustatic   = 4
TAMANHO menustatic   = 19
============================
TAMANHO vetorstatic  = 19
TAMANHO vetorstatic  = 19
TAMANHO vetorstatic  = 19
============================
TAMANHO vetordinamic = 10
TAMANHO vetordinamic = 10
TAMANHO vetordinamic = 11
```

O cálculo do tamanho com array de tamanho estático é calculado corretamente, porém é necessário algum ajuste para calcular corretamente um vetor dinâmico, mas já e algum começo

```
int lenarrayint(int p[]) {
   int nlen = 0;

   while(*(p++) || *p == 0 ) {
      nlen++;
   }
   return(nlen);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O vetor dentro do metodo agora é um ponteiro, então o tamanho será sempre 8 (se o seu arquivo for 64x), para calcular o tamanho dele, você deve criar um método que percorre o ponteiro e conte as posições.

```
int vec_len(int *vec){
    int c = -1;
    while(*(vec++))
        c++;
    return c;
}
```

Recomendo que use algum valor como `0` para identificar quando chegar no final do vetor.

Comment: Isto não faz o menor sentido.

Comment: Claro que faz, como se pega o tamanho de um ponteiro? Apenas percorrendo até a posição final, o `sizeof` em um ponteiro sempre retorna um númeroespecífico, e não acho que exista algo pronto em C que pegue quantos itens tem dentro de um ponteiro.

Comment: E como você sabe quando é o último elemento do ponteiro?

Comment: Então essa é a parte faltnado na resposta - o programador tem que convencionar um elemento que eserá o "marcador de final" - no caso, ele conta com uma convençao implicita de que ovetor se encerra no primeiro elemento de valor 0  - mas fora isso, esta é a rspotsa correta, e a outra é que não faz o menor sentido.

O que tem que ficar claro para o OP é que em C, não há metadados associados há um vetor  a não ser aqeules que você associa explicitamente,

As opçẽos são: ou ter um valro sentinela que indica o final (esse caso), ou contablizar o tamanho do vetor explicitamente em outra variável.

Comment: é um problema meio que sem solução então, se tivermos uma função que receba APENAS o vetor, e retorne o seu tamanho.